# How to declare inline variables without error messages?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition. When I write code with inline variable declarations like

```
var i:=1 to length(aStatement) do
```

the code compiles and runs as expected. No errors whatsoever. However, the IDE displays the code as if there were problems. Text is underlined with red squiggles and I'm told there are errors like "`Expected an identifier but received VAR...`" I get other "`Expected...but received`" and "`Undeclared identifier`" errors listed for code that follows the inline declaration.

What should I do to update the IDE to recognize this language change?

Comment: Error Insight has always been buggy. One of the first things I do when upgrading my Delphi version is to turn it off. It's never worked properly since it was first introduced. It's not Delphi's fault - the MS Visual Studio equivalent has the same sort of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution is to upgrade to Delphi 10.4, which fixes this [very well-known bug](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22158).

Comment: Since you are using the Community Edition, I would suspect that you get 10.4 (or newer) the next time you renew your licence.

Comment: There is no release of 10.4 CE yet

Comment: @DelphiCoder: I know. But with some luck there will be when the OP's license needs to be renewed (in 0 to 12 months). After all, to me it seems like 10.4 CE is already long overdue.

Comment: (Especially since this particular bug feels rather "embarrassing", given the fact that Embarcadero touted the inline variables feature as a major new feature in 10.3. I mean, 100% of those who actually tried to use inline variables in 10.3 must have noticed this bug and felt really disappointed!)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*to me it seems like 10.4 CE is already long overdue*" - hopefully, but I'm not holding my breathe for it. Embarcadero is currently working on 10.4.2, but there has not been any word whatsoever if any 10.4 CE will ever be released.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Having the "embarrassing" bug in the free CE that the company uses to get people to try Delphi and see how great the language and IDE are seems like less than ideal marketing, especially if it's easily correctable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I remember Marco Cantú was asked somewhere about a release of a 10.4 CE back when 10.4 was released. His answer was something like Embarcadero wants to give the paying customers an advantage first, before releasing a CE. But who knows when this advantage will be considered it lasted long enough.